# Which planets were shown during the celebrations at the end of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I'm watching *Return of the Jedi* again and I can see it's the remastered edition since the ghost of young Anakin from the prequel trilogy joins the ghosts of Yoda and Obi-Wan right at the end.

After the rebels destroy the Death Star at Endor, there is a series of celebrations across various planets.

Firstly what are the planets featuring celebrations? I can spot Naboo and Coruscant, but there are others I don't immediately recognise.

And is that a statue being toppled on Coruscant? What is the statue, I imagine it's related to the Emperor or the Empire, but can someone confirm?

Comment: Same question on movies: [What planets/systems are shown at the end of Return of the Jedi?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63897/what-planets-systems-are-shown-at-the-end-of-return-of-the-jedi). Answered, but with no sourcing.

Comment: The question about the statue is a dupe of [How are the celebration shots of Coruscant explained?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18852/how-are-the-celebration-shots-of-coruscant-explained/18858)

Comment: None in the original. The atrocities later added by Lucas' ego were a crime against humanity

Comment: There is only one: the planet, Endor.

Comment: @Mazura - wasn't that the forest moon of endor?

Comment: @KaiQing - No, that's the celestial body that the shield generator was on: The Forest Moon *of* Endor.

Comment: @Mazura - aah. Always wondered about that - if endor was a moon, what was it a moon of. But I agree then... Indeed, Endor was the only planet in those final scenes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This has mostly been covered by [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63927/44293) on our sister site. But here's some more details about the scene and when shots were added.

The original film didn't contain any celebrations outside of those in Endor, these were added in 1997 when the first three, [Bespin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bespin), [Tatooine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatooine) and [Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant).

It was in the 2004 DVD release that [Naboo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo) was added in, between Tatooine and Coruscant
(the below spoiler may ruin happy memories of gungan free scenes)

> Where if you listen carefully enough you'll notice a Gungan call out "wee-sa free!").

The extended changes are listed [here](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-wars-changes/)

<sub>In the below paragraph, clicking on the city will link you to a still image and clicking on the time will link you to a second or two before the scene starts.</sub>

From the below video we see the version in 2004 (the DVD release) After the funeral pyre scene and some shots of Endor the first Planet (City) we see is Bespin ([Cloud City](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCRri.png), [0:41](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=41s)) followed by Tatooine ([Mos Eisley Spaceport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4l4N.png), [0:54](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=54s)), Naboo ([Theed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93nio.png), [1:01](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=1m1s)), Coruscant ([Monument Plaza](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8BiI.png), [1:08](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=1m8s)) and finally back to Endor. [1:27](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=1m27s).

These cities are confirmed in the canon Junior Novelisation

> THERE ARE celebrations all across the galaxy. The claws of Palpatine have finally released their grip and free people pour into the streets of Coruscant, the plazas of Naboo, and the corridors of Cloud City. - And, yes, even in the cantinas of Mos Eisley.
>   <sub>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sub>

As for the fall of the statue. This is covered on a question on our own site [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18858/68872). Video can be seen from [1:18 of this clip](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=1m18s) on the left of the screen panning across to the right.

> The event, known as [Riot in Monument Plaza](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Riot_in_Monument_Plaza) in the new canon, was added to Return of the Jedi for the 1997 Special Edition. The first book to address this event in the new canon was [Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath). Coruscant citizens tore down a statue of the Emperor, but Imperial forces showed up and a riot broke out.
>
> > Three airspeeders swoop down from the traffic lanes above--Imperial police. Red-and-black helmets. The glow of their lights reflected back in their helmets.
> >
> > There comes no warning. No demand to stand down.
> >
> > The laser cannons at the fore of each airspeeder open fire. Red bolts sear the air. The crowd is cut apart. Bodies dropped and stitched with fire.
> >
> > But still, those gathered are not cowed. They are no longer a crowd. Now they are a mob. They start picking up chunks of the Palpatine statue and lobbing them up at the airspeeders. One of the speeders swings to the side to avoid an incoming chunk of stone--and it bumps another speeder, interrupting its fire.

Answer (score 18):

- [Cloud City](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_City), [Bespin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bespin)

[image]

- [Mos Eisley](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mos_Eisley), [Tatooine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatooine)

[image]

- [Theed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Theed), [Naboo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo)

[image]

- [Monument Plaza](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Monument_Plaza), [Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant)

[image]

[The statue was indeed of the Emperor.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Riot_in_Monument_Plaza) This is confirmed in the Legends novel *[X-Wing: Iron Fist](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-Wing:_Iron_Fist)* and the canon novel *[Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath)*, respectively.

> Before very long, they were actually tearing a statue of Palpatine down. It took cables and skimmers to knock it down. And then stormtroopers came.
>
> ---
>
> But still, those gathered are not cowed. They are no longer a crowd. Now they are a mob. They start picking up chunks of the Palpatine statue and lobbing them up at the airspeeders.

Comment: @CBredlow From what I remember in the original canon, the Jedi Temple was converted into the Imperial Palace; they kept the same structure and repurposed it. As a Sith, ruling the galaxy from a throne sat right in the middle of what used to be the Jedi Council chamber is kinda the ultimate victory.